# Will iOS app accepted on App Store if 80% of UI is rendered on UIWebView and 20% being native OCR

Tags: ios-appstore

I have a mobile website which at high level provides these functionalities:

1. Sign-in
2. Sign-up
3. Few forms where user can fill his additional details
4. Providing some capabilities to user based on information provided by him

Now I want to integrate OCR capabilities such as:

1. ID card scan
2. Debit card scan
3. Void check scan

So that some of the forms can be automatically filled by information extracted from these.

I am planning to make a native app in iOS consuming most of the forms, flow from my mobile website by rendering respective weburls on webview, and integrating vendor SDKs to provide OCR capabilities.

Will Apple accept my iOS app in App Store if I have 80% of flow, UI rendered on UIWebView and remaining 20% being integration and use of native vendor SDKs for OCR capabilities?

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#terms-conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This is walking into a grey area I don't know about. According to the Apple App guidelines, an app cannot just be a mobile version of a website. Since it seems as if you are just adding device capabilities, it will probably be rejected. Think of the Stack Overflow app. If it was just converting a website to an app without a address bar, it would not exist. They had to app-ify most(if not all) of the UI elements. You might be able to get away with leaving some things like a login form in the website form, but it has to look seamless.